# Как сделать в Wordpress'e, чтобы текст обтекал sidebar?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Поставил тему Frog Log 0.9.9 (ну, а вообще это касается любой темы) и захотелось, чтобы текст обтекал блок справа, сделал, чтобы текст был шириной в %, отключил в sidebar абсолютное позиционирование:

```
position: absolute;
```

заменил на:

```
position: relative;
float: right;
```

Но при этом, когда уменьшаешь окно, тема съезжает вниз и остается пустое пространство: т.е. тупо в начале идет сайдбар, прикрепленный справа, а потом текст ниже. Уже замучался пробовать, не знаю как сделать, помогите люди добрые.

Если нужен код CSS, то вот: http://pastebin.com/bWFcNgQv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте сделать не в % а в пикселях или используйте что то типа этого:

```
min-height:Z px;
height:auto !important;

min-width:Z px;
width:auto !important
```